# Javascript Vertical Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, widget, slider

I am trying to create a vertical slider widget in javascript. I am not looking for any plugins or libraries, I am trying to see how it can done using plain javascript . I think I got the general idea.

See here for what has been developed so far and do view source to see the code and please open the link in chrome.

http://eco-system2031.appspot.com/pages/ex5slider/verticalslider.html

Issues:

1) Sometimes the border ranges(eg: 0, 500) does not get calculated properly when I move the slider to the very top or the very bottom.

2) Sometimes the slider does not get released when I release the mouse(mouseup), the slider moves along with the mouse even after mouseup.

3) Any other things I need to make the code more robust and smooth using only javascript.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time and include the relevant code directly in the question. With that out of the way: use `preventDefault` in `mousedown`. It’ll prevent selection and dragging.

Comment: could you please provide JSFIDDLE

Answer (score 2):

And it is done. Thank you very one for your help.

Here is the HTML

```
    Minimum Value: <input id="minimum-value" type="text" value="0" /> <br/>
Maximum Value: <input id="maximum-value" type="text" value="500" /> <br/>
<input id="submit-value" type="submit" value="Submit" /> <br/>
Slider Value: <span id="sliderValue"></span> <br/> 
<div id="slider-container">
    <div id="slider-bar"></div>
    <div id="slider-handle"></div>
</div>
```

and here is the css

```
        #slider-container {
        width: 20px;
        height: 325px;
        margin: 100px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        background: #26AFE3;
        /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6 */
        -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
        -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
        border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    }

    #slider-bar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #E6E6E6;
        /* Safari 3-4. iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6 */
        -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
        -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Safari 5, Chromer, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
        border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    }

    #slider-handle {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        background: #7C7D82;
        position: relative;
        left: -2.5px;
        top: -10px;
        /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6 */
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px 20px 20px 20px;
        /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
        -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
        border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    }
```

here is the js

```
    (function () {
    // html elements
    var container = document.getElementById("slider-container");
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider-bar");
    var handle = document.getElementById("slider-handle");
    var submitVal = document.getElementById("submit-value");

    // initial values
    var minVal = Number( document.getElementById("minimum-value").value );
    var maxVal = Number( document.getElementById("maximum-value").value );

    var range = maxVal - minVal;
    var isSliding = false;


    // recalculate range
    submitVal.onclick = function() {
        minVal = Number( document.getElementById("minimum-value").value );
        maxVal = Number( document.getElementById("maximum-value").value );
        range = maxVal - minVal;
    };

    // the sliding function
    var move = function(e) {

        var mouseY = 0;
        var containerTop = 0;
        var newHeight = 0;
        var containerHeight = 0;
        var percentHght = 0;
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var sliderValue = 0;

        if (!e) var e = window.event;

        if( e.pageY ){ // all browsers except IE before version 9
            mouseY = e.pageY;

        } else if ( e.clientY ) { // IE before version 9
            mouseY = e.clientY;
        }   

        containerTop = container.offsetTop;
        newHeight = mouseY - containerTop;
        containerHeight = container.offsetHeight;
        percentHght = newHeight * 100 / containerHeight;

        if( (percentHght <= 100) && (percentHght >= 0) ) {
            slider.style.height = (percentHght) + '%';
            y = 100 - percentHght;
            x = y * range / 100;

        } else if( percentHght < 0 ) {
            percentHght = 0;
            slider.style.height = (percentHght) + '%';
            y = 100 - percentHght;
            x = y * range / 100;

        } else if( percentHght > 100 ) {
            percentHght = 100;
            slider.style.height = (percentHght) + '%';
            y = 100 - percentHght;
            x = y * range / 100;
        }
        sliderValue = Math.round(x);
        document.getElementById('sliderValue').innerHTML = sliderValue + minVal;
    };

    // adding the slide functionality
    var addSlide = function() {
        isSliding = true;
        if ( !window.addEventListener ){
            document.attachEvent('onmousemove',move);
        } else {
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
        }
    };

    // removing the slide functionality
    var cancelSlide = function() {
        if( isSliding ) {
            if ( window.removeEventListener ) {
                document.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
            } else if ( window.detachEvent ) {
                document.detachEvent('onmousemove', move );
            }
        }
    };

    // cancelling event bubbling
    // cancelling default event action
    var cancelBubble = function(e) {
        var evt = e ? e:window.event;

        if( evt.stopPropogation ){
            evt.stopPropogation();
        }

        if( evt.cancelBubble != null ){
            evt.cancelBubble = true;
        }

        if( evt.preventDefault ){
            evt.preventDefault();
        } else {
            evt.returnValue = false;
        }
    };

    // capture events
    //capturing the mousedown on the handle
    handle.onmousedown = function(e) {
        addSlide();
        cancelBubble(e);
    }

    //capture the mouseup on the handle
    handle.onmouseup = function(e) {
        cancelSlide();
        cancelBubble(e);
    }

    // capture the mouse up on the slider
    slider.onmouseup = function(e) {
        cancelSlide();
        cancelBubble(e);
    }

    // capture the mouse down on the slider
    slider.onmousedown = function(e) {
        move(e);
        cancelBubble(e);
    }

    // capture the mouse up on the container
    container.onmouseup = function(e) {
        cancelSlide();
        cancelBubble(e);
    }

    // capture the mouse down on the container
    container.onmousedown = function(e) {
        move(e);
        cancelBubble(e);
    }

    // capture the mouse up on the window
    document.onmouseup = function(e) {
        cancelSlide();
        cancelBubble(e);
    }

})();
```

here is the jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/nPaKp/

and here is a link out side jsfiddle

http://eco-system2031.appspot.com/pages/ex5slider/verticalslider.html

Comment: I gave your answer an upvote...UNTIL I discovered there is no way to invert its operation (min on top, max on bottom.)  Alas, I struggled too long with trying to accomplish that, and now I can no longer remove my upvote.  Make a deal with me-I'll be happy for my upvote to be yours if you'll make the slider work min-side up.  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, add this:

```
slider.onmouseuout = slider.onmouseup;
```

sort of thing to the end of each onmouseup declaration and the problem of the slider still following the pointer if it slips off the slider handle goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Great addition!

Also change this:

```
stopPropogation() --> stopPropagation() // spelling mistake
```

A better way is to avoid stopPropagation altogether as it's bad practice. Interesting article: [Dangers of stopping event propagation](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)

If you want a larger handle click area e.g. when adding touch support:

```
#slider-handle {
    position: relative;
    width: 75px;
    height: 48px;
    left: -32.5px;
    top: -24px;
    border-radius: 50% / 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;  /* remove after test */
    cursor: grab;
}
#slider-handle:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%/50%;
}
```